# NSURLDownload Cancelling

Tags: objective-c, macos

So I am using NSURLDownload in a program, and it requires that I give the user an option to cancel the donwload.  I tried using the -cancel method but it only works up until the device starts receiving data at which point i cannot find a way to stop it. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the [`ASIHTTPRequest` library](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) that provides a lot of nice abstractions and utility methods.

To cancel a request in the library, you can just do `[request cancel]`!  Take a look at ["How to use" code sample page](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).